# How to create interaction variable between only 1 variable with all other variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

When using the SciKit learn `PolynomialFeatures` package it is possible to do the following:

1. Take features: `x1`, `x2`, `x3`
2. Create interaction variables: `[x1, x2, x3, x1x2, x2x3, x1x3]` using `PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True)`

My problem is that I only want the interaction terms between `x1` and all other terms meaning:

`[x1, x2, x3, x1x2, x1x3]`, I do not want `x2x3`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why don't you get wanted columns of the output array by slicing? For example if you define the object like `poly = PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False, interaction_only=True)` and fit transform like ``y = poly.fit_transform(X)``, then you can get only 'X0' interactions by `y=y[:,:X.shape[1]*2-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make them yourself no? PolynomialFeatures doesn't do anything particularly innovative.